# apache httpd.confg missing LoadModule

Tags: apache

Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Aug 24 2015 18:11:25

Hi I just recently installed apache and referring this url
http://www.tecmint.com/monitor-apache-web-server-load-and-page-statistics/

it states that 
'#LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so'
should be uncomment.

but in the httpd.conf file there are no values in Load Module section and there are no default modules to uncomment. Do we need to do any thing extra or is it ok to just add this value it?

'#Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support

'#

`# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you

`# have to place corresponding`LoadModule' lines at this location so the

`# directives contained in it are actually available *before* they are used.

`# Statically compiled modules (those listed by`httpd -l') do not need

`# to be loaded here.

`#

`# Example:

`# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so

`#
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

`#

`# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run

thanks

Comment: _but the `httpd.conf` file does not seem to be blank_ <- what do you mean?

Comment: I have updated the post